# Disable a UIButton until all attributes of a UIManagedObject set?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

How can I disable a UIButton until a UIManagedObject's properties (attributes) are all filled out? And I mean, what event can trigger that? What notifications or protocol method should I write?

Answer (score 0):

KVO (key-value observing) might be your best bet. Check out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

You could also use `NSNotificationCenter` but I don't think that's really the best route, unless the view controller owning the `UIButton` isn't related to the managed object.